# Sum of the series $\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{1.3.5.7..(2k-1)}{3.6.9..(3k)}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

$\{S_n\}= \sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1.3.5.7..(2k-1)}{3.6.9..(3k)}$

I applied the D Alembert Ratio test on:

$S_\infty=\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1.3}{3.6}+\frac{1.3.5}{3.6.9}+\frac{1.3.5.7..(2k-1)}{3.6.9..(3k)}$ as $k$ tends to $\infty$

so,
$\frac{a_n}{a_{n+1}}=\frac{(3n+1).(3n+2).(3n+3)}{2n.(2n+1)}$ which will go to $\infty (>1)$ as $n$ tends $\infty$, so the series is convergent.

But how to find the actual limit of the series? Kindly help.

Comment: $\mathcal{S}_n$ can be written as $\{\mathcal{S}_n \} = \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{(2k)!}{6^k \, (k!)^2} $

Comment: sorry @AnneBauval I am not able to correlate the two questions

Comment: The correlation is direct: $1+\lim S_n=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\binom{2k}k(1/6)^k=\frac1{\sqrt{1-4/6}}.$

Comment: @AnneBauval I could spot the correlation by writing first few terms but still I am not able to follow the solution there from the start.. For example I dont know how to make sense of $C_{2n}^{n}$ ...how can we select $2n$ items from $n$ items...thats how I know it

Comment: You don't need that combinatorial interpretation (btw, $C_{2n}^n=\binom{2n}n$ is select $n$ items from $2n$, not the converse). Simply remember that $\binom mk=\frac{m!}{k!(n-k)!}$ hence the $S_n=\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{(2k)!}{6^k \, (k!)^2}$ in the first comment above becomes $S_n=\sum_{k=1}^n\binom{2k}k\frac1{6^k}.$

Comment: @AnneBauval I could understand the outline of the solution mentioned in the post. But still I was wondering if there is a solution which does not use calculus, and without solving differential equations...I mean a more direct solution without first generalizing the problem..

Comment: That proof is so usual that I doubt there is a simpler one. See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series#Summation_of_the_binomial_series